# what pageobject to return from a pageobject back action

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects

In my application, a record page has a 'Back' button. The page can be accessed from either a home page or a list of records page; and the back button should return to the previous page. What should the back method return?

One way is to pass a parameter to `RecordPageObject` so that it tracks what it should return when back is pressed. 
    class RecordPageObject {

```
  T back(Class<T> returnPageObjecType) {
    click("Back"); // some function to click on Back button.
    if (comingFromHome) { 
      return (T) PageObjectFactory.createHomePageObject();
    } else {
      return (T) PageObjectFactory.createListPageObject();
    }
  }

}
```

In this case, the calling code will be:

```
// calling code
HomePageObject currentPage =  RecordPageObject.back(HomePageObject.class);
```

Option 2 is to only do `click("Back")` in `back()` function and write calling code as follows:

```
RecordPageObject rec = .... // something to land on RecordPage
rec.back();
HomePageObject currentPage =  PageObjectFactory.createHomePageObject();
```

I guess, yet another option will be to pass the PageObject's type as a generic parameter to the `RecordPageObject<T>` and store it as a member. This will save us from passing that value in `back()` function.

Comment: The simple answer is: make the calling function keep track of it. The more complicated answer lies in inheritance and `interface`.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to use the first approach that you have used.

```
HomePageObject currentPage =  RecordPageObject.back(HomePageObject.class);
```

This clearly explains the *flow* of your application and this is exactly you should be doing. The second approach that you have followed has one drawback. Your creating the page object, however the `back` should be doing that task! (As that is supposed to be functioning such in your UI)